# View a page/file if user is logged and has page/file ids assigned, in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need help on Laravel v8.
I'm trying to have a page to view owners manual and I want only logged in users with assigned owners manual ids can view the page.
So far, I have created owners_manual table and added owners_manual_id for user table. On the backend user edit page, I add multiple owners manuals for this user so that when he click on the link to view one of these owners manual, he will be able to view it if he's logged in. It working out fine on the backend but how do I construct the frontend view? Please help me out, I'm stuck at this point...
I want to create a frontend page to view owners manual but I don't know how...

Comment: If you want to hide certain elements in the view, check out Laravel's authorization documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#via-blade-templates Consider also creating Policies and/or Gates

Comment: what does it mean "It working out fine on the backend but how do I construct the frontend view"? would you like to display a 404 page? a 403? something else?

Comment: Hi @Jack. I want to create a page to view the owners manual on the frontend but I don't know how.

Comment: sorry @Brenden still not understanding what you are achieving...

Comment: @Jack. I want to create a owners manual page for the users to view their owners manuals. So I created a database table named owners_manuals. On my users table I added owners_manual_id so that i can assign the owners manuals to the users. On the backend, I added owners manuals and also added owners manuals to some users. Now I am trying to create a frontend view but i don't know how...